# Which character does this picture depict?

Tags: marvel, x-men, character-identification

I found this image online and can't put a name to him and it's driving me crazy. I have tried searching every possible descriptor about the image and maybe I'm looking at it but it looks as if he has an electric bat but nothing comes up.

The stylised "X" on his shoulder made me think he was part of X-men but nothing comes up for that either.

[image]

Comment: For the record, I found this within seconds by using google images '[image search](https://tinyurl.com/hbkheqe)' facility.

Comment: I could also have used [tineye](https://www.tineye.com/search/c1dc7670a5412e93ab58c5d94f888fd9e3751b9b/) to achieve much the same result.

Comment: Right click -> "Search Google for Image". First result.

Answer (score 10):

This is an original creation by a digital artist named [Dan LuVisi](http://danluvisiart.deviantart.com/art/Gabriel-the-9th-LMS-356340561) for a book called [Last Man Standing: Killbook of a Bounty Hunter](http://naldzgraphics.net/inspirations/dan-luvisi-lms-character-design-illustrations-youd-want-to-see/). The character's name is Martyr.

> Thomas Kline was once one of Amerika's most notorious, feared and
> unobtainable hit-men. With a combined record of over 300 confirmed
> kills and many facial reconstructions he has proven to be a
> resourceful and dangerous man. Recently however, Kline became
> addicted to the drug TMU and began consuming it at an enormous rate.
> Slowly the drug overtook his brain turning him into nothing but a
> psychopathic berserk serial killer called Martyr.
>
> Martyr was eventually captured by the Paladin Gabriel and sent to the
> level-9 facility where he met his current team-mate and leader Abaddon
> and Dante.
>
> <sub><sup>[Comicvine Profile - MARTYR](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/martyr/4005-83861/) - (with spelling and grammar corrected)</sup></sub>